# Windows metro app - animating my UI?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, animation, microsoft-metro

I am a beginner in Windows 8 metro app development. As I only understand C# at the moment, then I wrote every code in C#. I tested the app and it works pretty well, the only thing it is missing is the simple animation that most modern app have.

an animation like when I want to make my StackPanel visible it is fading from the left to right, is it possible in C# and XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use blend for that.  It comes with VS and it is *by far* easier than doing it in VS.  At the very least generate it in Blend and then copy it to VS where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Blend is the way through which you can do the animation.
Blend generally comes with Visual Studio package. So try to open your app in Blend and do the animations. If you have any trouble in doing the animations please let me know.